# Is it considered an Auth* anti-pattern to call the AssumeRole API from a browser context, and if so, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-cognito, aws-sts

Someone alluded to me that it was inexplicable to them why anyone would ever call STS' AssumeRole API from the browser.

I told them I have resources in multiple accounts to reduce blast radius, etc. but I still want my Cognito app clients to be able to access those resources.

Is it an anti-pattern to use STS in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the case for my corporation because:

All user accounts was created on the master account. corporation-account

All the departments manage have their own department-account

Whenever the corporation's IT guy would like to list/update/delete user account, they should be able to do so, without accessing the departments's account.

Also billing for each departments would be very clear ( the reason for splitting to multiple AWS accounts )